# How to call a private method via dot notation inside constructor?

Tags: javascript, oop

this is the resume: How to call a private method via dot notation inside constructor?:

I know there's a lot of question asking the same... in this particulary I coulnd't find anywhere so I decided to ask.

How receiveAttackFrom() method can be private ?
so if I try this...

```
soldier1.receiveAttackFrom(soldier2, 50)
```

would throw an error

```
var Soldier = function(_name, _life, _damage) {

var name = _name
var life = _life
var damage = _damage

this.getName = function() {return name}
this.getLife = function() {return life}
this.getDamage = function() {return damage}

this.setLife = function(_life) {life = _life}

this.attack = function(_targ) {

    _targ.receiveAttackFrom(this, this.getDamage());
}

// how to put this as a private method? :
this.receiveAttackFrom = function(_other, _damage) {

    this.setLife( this.getLife() - _damage )    
}
```

}

```
// MAIN
var soldier1 = new Soldier('jonas', 100, 25);
var soldier2 = new Soldier('mark', 90, 30);

soldier1.attack(soldier2);
// so if I try this...
// soldier1.receiveAttackFrom(soldier2, 50)
// would throw an error
```

Comment: Why do you think it should be private?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: there's no error in this code... I just want to make a public method to become a private method. but using dot notation inside constructor

Comment: If the function is available via dot notation, it's not private any more.

Comment: so the only thing is to pass 2 objects as a parameter... making a private method. that's what l was looking for

var reciveAttkFrom (obj1, obj2, dmg)

Answer (score 0):

```
var _self = this;
this.receiveAttackFrom = function(_other, _damage) {
    _self.setLife( _self.getLife() - _damage )    
}
```

Comment: Comments/explanation on your answer will help the OP and improve its long term value.

Answer (score 0):

Define the function at the start of your constructor with `var` and bind it to `this`:

```
var receiveAttackFrom = function (_other, _damage) {
    this.setLife( this.getLife() - _damage )    
}.bind(this);
```

Then call it inside the constructor without prefix:

```
receiveAttackFrom(arg1, arg2);
```